# Improper IDFA usage, your app is not respecting the Limit ad tracking setting in ios

Tags: ios, admob, app-store-connect

I have checked the iTC settings
[image]

I have uploaded the same app 2 days ago and it works fine but when today I uploaded the same app with a minor bug fix it's now showing this error.
[image]

I'm using Admob, Revmob and Applovin. But I know admob is the culprit.

Comment: So how about contacting those folks from admob then?

Comment: Could you get around this? I'm hitting a wall since yesterday evening on this exact same issue with flurry, mopub, inmobi, millennial and iAds... all latest versions. I Did put a symbolic breakpoint on the [ASIdentifierManager advertisingIdentifier] and got it to only be called if isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled returns true. Could it be that apple broke something?

Comment: Yeah I'm having the same issue. Game uploaded okay, rejected for another reason and couldn't reupload today. I'm using RevMob, Flurry, app-c, TapForTap, Tapjoy, Chartboost. Not sure who the culprit(s) is(are) but they're all the latest SDKs.

Comment: I just contacted Apple about the issue. Either they broke something or a lot of app submissions are going to have to wait a while for all the 3rd party vendors to update their SDKs.

Comment: On my end I found the culprit: mopub. I managed to get the app to be validated by replacing the direct references to ASIdentifierManager in mopub source by a NSClassFromString(@"ASIdentifierManager") call... not sure what the validation process does exactly, but it's not doing it right :)

Comment: Yes I have reported to Admob team also

Comment: I believe revmob may have had some issues in the past with this as well, but I got an app approved using their latest build. Make sure you're using the last versions of all the ad frameworks. The IDFA policies were not included long ago.

Comment: Latest revmob and startapp doesn't have IDFA issues

Comment: You managed to make your app be accepted. . . by circumventing the user's request to exercise their legal right for privacy. Stay classy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution for me was to trash the `Admob-SDK` and integrate the [`Startapp-SDK`](https://developers.startapp.com/), It is compliant with the apple's new IDFA policies, you can read their [documentation here](https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/Documentation/wiki/iOS-InApp-Documentation).

I will let you know if Admob guys fix this issue.

---

From Applovin Folks

> I wanted to update you on an IDFA change Apple made on Saturday. Apple's systems are automatically rejecting apps that are uploaded if the app has SDKs in it that access IDFA and still support pre-iOS 6 (where IDFA wasn't present). Our new SDK 2.3.6 (and in Unity, 3.0.9) will now pass Apple's screen since we have deprecated support for iOS 4 and 5 (only 1.5% of traffic); and note that many popular SDKs in the market act similarly so you may need to work with your other vendors on updating their software for compatibility.

---

Edit

#### I uploaded an update today(5th May, 2014) with admob 6.8.0 and it was uploaded sucessfully

Comment: The Google Mobile Ads SDK and the Google Conversion Tracking SDK utilize Apple's advertising identifier introduced in iOS 6 (IDFA). The SDKs use IDFA under the guidelines laid out in the iOS developer program license agreement, including Limit Ad Tracking.

Comment: @William I was using SDK 6.8, As I have mentioned earlier 2 day back it was working, I submitted the app with the same sdk but then I rejected my binary and after two days I tried again and it failed. May be it's working now but I didn't check

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Yes when i removed Admob-SDK i was able to upload the binary. But is there any other solution rather integrating new SDK.

Comment: @IKR so Apple must have changed the algorithm they use to vet apps in the last 2 days. That doesn't change the fact that the Admob SDK abides by the guidelines laid out in the iOS developer program licence agreement.

Comment: @William yes you may be right, but StartApp sdk was not broking anything so that means AdMob was using IDFA but not properly, may be I'm wrong. I don't know is it fixed right now or not.

Answer (score 1):

It validated for me also.  Initially I thought admob was the issue and might have been but after removing TapJoy and all references the app validated.

Comment: TapJoy issued an update today (10.0.2) specifically addressing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove both InMobi and Conversant (aka ValueClick/Greystripe).  Then it stopped being an "Invalid Binary" and went into "Waiting for Review".  I can confirm that AdColony, Chartboost and TapJoy all definitely pass Apple's check with latest SDKs.  InMobi issued an SDK update on 29/4 (v4.3.0) but it does NOT pass this test.

Comment: Hey Chris. I'm from InMobi. We wrote a blog here: http://www.inmobi.com/blog/2014/05/06/idfa-and-how-to-avoid-getting-your-app-rejected-by-itunes on this topic. This issue should be fixed by now.

Comment: I can't find an SDK update since the one on April 29th that failed.  Are you saying that Apple has changed the check to approve InMobi then?

Comment: Can't really comment on that although I can confirm that apps with the InMobi SDK are being approved now. :)

Comment: We submitted an app today with the same SDKs for InMobi and Conversant and so far it's not been automatically rejected.

Answer (score 1):

I used Google AdMob and Flurry. With AdSupport framework removed, shows it's AdMob that's the culprit.

I can't find any recently released SDK for AdMob and Flurry, so I just change the status back to ready for binary upload again, select the answer as shown above in the screen dump, and it works for me, some screen dumps on my blog below. Hope this helps. Thanks!

http://new2objectivec.blogspot.com.au/2014/05/app-store-invalid-binary-error-due-to.html

Answer (score 0):

I've submitted an app with AdMob today with the same settings.
It's now in Waiting for Review state.

I've used Xcode Organizer to submit the app. Maybe Apple have re-adjusted the validation.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your issue is actually coming from Applovin, not AdMob. Others seem to have succeeded with AdMob in some way, so it would make sense. These guys have come to the conclusion that it is Applovin -> [Source](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/business-legal-app-store/118279-anyone-got-improper-advertising-identifier-idfa-usage-error-when-submitting-app-today.html)

**I've finally got mine to validate!** If you remove AdSupport.framework, any culprits causing this failed validation will NOT cause a linker error. So the SDK's that are showing errors are the ones using the framework correctly, remove any others and try again. In my case Millennial was the problem.

Comment: Not in my case.. I replaced Admob with startapp and it give no error. Also when I remove AdSupport.framework only admob lib was giving linker errors

Comment: Ah that's a shame. I have 2 of my 4 Ad providers relying on the AdSupport framework. I've tried taking out one of them leaving just AdMob and I was still getting the failed validation. I can't take it out as I need it to be AdMob.

Comment: Actually I've just read somewhere else that the SDK's that give linker errors when removing AdSupport framework are actually the ones that are fine because they're directly accessing them. It's the weak references that Apple are regarding as incorrect usage. I've added to my answer for anyone scanning through to give a try. - This just worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded an app with admob sdk 6.8.0 successfully today (after removed mmedia sdk 5.2.0). I think you need to check other ad network sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I had an app that was at state "waiting for upload" before 12th April. After which the itunes guidelines were updated to contain section of IDFA usage when the app state is "Prepare for upload". So, because of this situation every time I turned in the binary I would get an error of "Improper IDFA usage".

For me the solution was

1.upload a binary without IDFA sdks.

2.make it "developer rejected".

3.Update the settings of IDFA after choosing "ready to upload binary" option from itunes connect.

4.Upload a new binary with IDFA sdks.