# "Invalid Binary" with Improper Advertising Identifier [IDFA] Usage

Tags: ios, ads

I'm new to IOS.
I used mobileAds framework in my app.
I submitted my app on apple store last three months and now I submitted my new version app on apple store.I didn't check IDFA check box and released it.I got my status change to "Invalid Binary" and mail:

Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
"myapp". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
corrected:

Improper Advertising Identifier [IDFA] Usage. Your app contains the
Advertising Identifier [IDFA] API but you have not indicated its usage
on the Prepare for Upload page in iTunes Connect.

Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page
and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission
process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then
deliver the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team

Should I check all of the check box this time?

Sorry for my poor English and Thanks in advanced.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting error improper advertising identifier \[IDFA\] usage,when i am validating my app in xCode 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23335230/getting-error-improper-advertising-identifier-idfa-usage-when-i-am-validating)

Comment: Please do a search and look at the list of Related questions shown to the right. There are several questions dealing with this IDFA issue.

Comment: If you are not using the latest SDK versions of various ad networks, this would be expected. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315368/improper-idfa-usage-your-app-is-not-respecting-the-limit-ad-tracking-setting-in) for related information.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here:

See the screenshot in the first thread:

[Improper IDFA usage, your app is not respecting the Limit ad tracking setting in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315368/improper-idfa-usage-your-app-is-not-respecting-the-limit-ad-tracking-setting-in/24342882#24342882)

Comment: you should include the key information from the link rather than just the link itself, in case the link does not work in future.